# Cannot create users as administrator. Users can register by themselves but I can't add users (site exported directly from Drupal Gardens)

Tags: 7, users

I have a weird problem with my user registration in 2 of my sites. When I go to the "Add User" link under "People" menu, I fill in the information of the user and press the "Sign Up" button. The page refreshes, there is no error message or a confirmation message that the user has been added and the user is not added. I have checked the error messages in the "Reports" section and no entry is created there either.

When I turn on the user registration from "Configuration - Account Settings" a user can create a new account and I can edit the account as admin but I still can't create new user accounts.

Some extra information:

The site that I created is a direct export from Drupal Gardens. I did not mess with any code. It's pretty clean, direct export.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this and find out what is causing this strange issue?

Edit: for the time being I use the workaround to manually register through the regular user registration form and then disable the manual user registration and edit the users as admin but I'd prefer the normal functionality for obvious reasons.

Comment: Did you check that you have the right _Permissions_  (admin/people/permissions) ?

Comment: Yes. This is one of the first things that I checked. The account that I'm trying to do that with is actually user/1. Besides that, if I didn't have enough permissions to do that, I would get an error message. I do not get any error messages: neither directly nor at the site's error log reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. However, once I disabled three Drupal Gardens custom modules, I was able to add users. The modules are:

- Gardens Features
- Gardens Feedback
- Gardens Required Features

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you copied the .htaccess file when you migrated your site ? Page submits leading nowhere are often caused by improper .htaccess configuration.

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess file is actually the one from the original Drupal installation. Double checked it.

Comment: How is your PHP error reporting configured ? Often, a too low error reporting level leads to pages failing to be constructed silently, without any ouput to give hints about the problem because PHP fails but the debug messages don't get to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but the solution above cant solve it. let me take you through the steps.

The problem occured when i was moving my drupal files from my localhost to server, this problem may arise when you didnt copy all your enabled modules when moving to the server.

**kindly check all your modules in `sites/all/modules` both on local machine and live server.**
It might help you
Thanks.